# Python regex: Match 1 or 2 digits, return longest

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling to understand my error. Consider these examples:

> A 9 minutes delay experienced
>
> a 10 minutes delay

I want to extract 9 and 10, respectively.

So I tried this:

```
.*(\d{1,2})(?:\s)?(min|m|hour|hr|h|minutes|minute)
```

[test link](http://pythex.org/?regex=.*(%5Cd%5Cd)(%3F%3A%5Cs)%3F(min%7Cm%7Chour%7Chr%7Ch%7Cminutes%7Cminute)&test_string=delay%20of%209%20min%20was%20recorded%20%0AA%209%20minutes%20delay%20experienced%0A%0Aa%2010%20minutes%20&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

But for the last case, group returns `0` instead of `10`. I thought `\d{1,2}` was greedy, and hence would return the longest match. 
Other, unsuccessful attempts:

```
.*(\d+)(?:\s)?(min|m|hour|hr|h|minutes|minute) 
.*([0-9]+)(?:\s)?(min|m|hour|hr|h|minutes|minute)
```

Comment: `\d{1,2}` is greedy, but so is `.*`, and `.*` gets to go first.

Comment: Thanks! I have not completely understood how it works, but to fix it should I just do: .*?

Comment: I'd take out the `.*` entirely. If you're using a function that implicitly anchors the match at the start of the string, don't. For example, if you're using `re.match`, you should be using `re.search` instead.

Comment: You just need to use `re.search(r'(\d{1,2})\s?(?:min|m|hour|hr?|minutes?)', s).group(1)` or `re.findall(r'(\d{1,2})\s?(?:min|m|hour|hr?|minutes?)', s)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `.*` at the start of the pattern that grabs any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then starts backtracking, trying to accommodate the substrings for the subsequent subpatterns. That way, you lose the all the digits but the last in the number.

You need to discard the `.*` completely and use `re.search` or `re.findall` with `r'(\d{1,2})\s?(?:min|m|hour|hr?|minutes?)'` (see the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/XmBsiL/1)):

```
import re
ss = ['A 9 minutes delay experienced','a 10 minutes delay']
for s in ss:
    m = re.search(r'(\d{1,2})\s?(?:min|m|hour|hr?|minutes?)', s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/SukEbj)

This pattern will match when it finds:

- `(\d{1,2})`  - Group 1 capturing 1 or 2 digits (use `+` instead of `{1,2}` if you expect longer numbers)
- `\s?`  - 1 or 0 whitespaces (maybe `*` is even more reliable)
- `(?:min|m|hour|hr?|minutes?)`  - `min`, `m`, `hour`, `h`, `hr`, etc., a non-capturing group that is only used for grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm `.*` is greedy allready, however you want to extract two numbers - keep it simple, something like `.*?(\d+).*(\d+)` will do the job

Answer (score 0):

`".*?([0-9]+).*"` is an answer.

`.*` is greedy : it will match the more possible. "A 1" in the "A 10 minutes delay" case. Letting the `([0-9]+)` group with only "0" left.

`.*?` is lazy : it will match the minimum possible, letting the priority to the subsequent `([0-9]+)` group to match the 2 digits "10". ( `+` is greedy, it wants to match the more possible).

To test the behaviour of the "?":
https://regex101.com/